# Apt install size & remove size are different

Tags: apt, gnome, dpkg

[image]

Let's say I installed mumble server. At the time of installation, it showed X MB of storage will be used (can't remember).

If I uninstall those programs, the size is relatively less than that of installation size.

Why is that so? Do I need to remove its configuration? How can I find app-specific configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is normal. This happens because of dependencies.
If you run `sudo apt-get autoremove` or `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge` (to remove all configs), you then get expected size.

Next time please read about APT internals first by using docs like

- https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.package-meta-information.html#id-1.8.6.8.13
- https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.apt-get.html#sect.apt.install
- https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/package-management .

or whole https://debian-handbook.info/download/stable/debian-handbook.pdf .